# Is there is any way that i can define user input as my string array length?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to solve the problem where the user input array is required. But when I pass the declared int after getting input from the user, I'm getting an error of expression that must have a constant value.
The code goes like this.

```
#include <stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    //string name[a]; this causes the error of expression of contant must define
    //ive changed to 
    string name[1000];//this causes no error and run the code
    //but i want to take the length of array from the user input just like commented code
    string out1, out2;
    for (int i = 0;i < a;i++) {
        cin >> name[i];
    }
    // cout<<name[0].size();
        // int size=b.size(), size2=c.size();
    string  b;
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i < a;i++) {
        out1 = "", out2 = "";
        x = 0;
        for (int j = 0;j < (name[i].size());j++) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                b = name[i];
                out1 += b[x];
            }
            if (x % 2 == 1) {
                out2 += b[x];
            }
            x++;

        }
        out2 += "\n";
        cout << out1 << " " << out2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays must be defined with constant length.  Why don't you use `std::vector<>` ? It will solve your purpose

Comment: There is a way to do everything, in C++. You just have to find the right chapter in your C++ textbook that explains how to do it. In this case you want to find the chapter in your textbook that explains how to use `std::vector`.